# Add attribute to all controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

I want to add the `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`  attribute to all of my controllers so that I can opt in to the behavior instead of having to opt out on most controllers. I tried adding it like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>();
});
```

However, I get this error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute' cannot be used as type parameter 'TFilterType'
```

I guess this attribute is not actually a filter so it can't be used like this, but is there some other way I can globally apply this?

Comment: Maybe [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can solve your problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to apply `ApiExplorerSettings` to all your controllers? What behavior are you trying to opt-in to?

Comment: See [Use `ApiExplorer` to document an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-apiexplorer-to-document-an-app).

Answer (score 1):

As Kirk Larkin said, you could consider using the model Convention to set the IgnoreApi to true for all models.

More details, you could refer to below example:

1.Create the class:

```
  public class IgnoreApiConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        // Add the [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] attribute to all controllers
        controller.ApiExplorer.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

2.Register it inside the controller service:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new IgnoreApiConvention());
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Common way to apply attribute to many classes is through inheritance. Create a base class for your controller and decorate it with the attribute. Then every controller should inherit from a base controller with attribute.

It also depends on the attribute parameters (properties) you want to set. I see people trying to dynamically apply the logic of this attribute. [Dynamically Ignore WebAPI method on controller for api explorer documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951728/dynamically-ignore-webapi-method-on-controller-for-api-explorer-documentation)

Comment: I was really hoping for a solution that I can put globally in Program.cs, my goal is that I shouldn't have to modify all my constructors. If this is the only solution I'd rather just apply the attribute.

Comment: you don't have to change constructors - c# calls parent default constructor base() automatically. but you will have to change all classes if you don't have a base controller class yet (by adding `: BaseController` to class declaration)